# select all X type of elements but not the same type again inside them

Tags: css, css-selectors

for example, if there are several `DIV` elements, one inside another. lets say 3 levels.
how would you go about selecting only the 2nd level of Divs, not knowing how deep they might be,
and not able to give more classes?

```
// html example of a possible DOM
<div class="level1'>
    <a>
        <div>
            <a>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a>
        <div></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

selectors overview:
`div.level1 > div` => (BAD) would return nothing because Div is inside `a`

`div.level1 > a > div` => (BAD) the 2nd level div's might be deeper, and the exact xpath should not be written

is there some kind of CSS selector combinations that would return **'find the elements but never go find inside them'**, so then `div.level1 div` will return only the 2nd-level Divs but not the ones that might be inside them (something of that sort). I find this a very powerful thing to have.

Comment: There should be a selector like this. gives great powers.  CSS sadly lacks many good selectors

Answer (score 0):

Not likely.
But what you can do is set desired property on the level >= 2 (`div.level1 div`) and negate it on all the divs below level 2 (`div.level1 div div`).

Of course, there's always an option of using different classes for each level.

Comment: yes but i like to refrain from using classes as much as possible, because sometimes you have too many elements on the page, and giving each a class will increase the overall weight of the page

Comment: @vsync IMHO, bandwidth is the last thing you should worry about. It's like writing all code in a single line to save on whitespaces.

Comment: yes thats what i'm doing now, I have to go and reset all the properties I have previously set on the element that Ii DID wanted it to catch. thanks for taking the time to posting your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your first selector looks absolutely fine. Just check out this example CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a, div {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        background-color: red
    }
    div.level1 > div {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Only the second level DIV is matched as it is a direct child of the div.level1.

BTW: Your HTML makes no sense at all. DIVs inside of inline elements are bad. But links inside of links are even worse :)

Comment: I made a mistake in this. nothing would be selected from the first selector, because there are no direct div childs to the main div. my html is just an example, I know it's not valid. my real life need for this is tables in side tables.. 3 levels deep. too many TD's to select, and ones over-ride each-other.

Comment: Try Nikita's solution to select all divs and then overwrite deeper ones. There is no CSS selector to select levels of child nodes. The only other solution is doing the job with javaScript. You can e.g. use Prototypes down() (http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/down/) function to select a speific level and add a class name to those elements. But you CAN'T do that with CSS alone like you want to do.

Comment: thanks. I think the CSS committee still have to work on the basics before going crazy with fancy CSS3 selectors. this type of selector would mean a lot.

Comment: The very design of CSS makes it pretty hard to come up with such selectors, especially seeing as browsers usually parse selectors from right to left, working *up* the DOM tree rather than *down* as they search for nodes to match.